# Kubernetes internal socket.io connection

Tags: kubernetes, websocket

I am following this image architecture from K8s

[image]

However I can not seem to connect to socket.io server **from within** the cluster using the service name

Current situation:

From POD B

- Can connect directly to App A's pod using WS ( ws://10.10.10.1:3000 ) ✅
- Can connect to App A's service using HTTP ( http://orders:8000 ) ✅
- **Can not connect to App A's service using WS ( ws://orders:8000 )** ❌

From outside world / Internet

- **Can connect to App A's service using WS ( ws://my-external-ip/orders )**  ✅ // using traefik to route my-external-ip/orders to service orders:8000
- Can connect to App A's service using HTTP ( http://my-external-ip/orders )  ✅ // using traefik to route my-external-ip/orders to service orders:8000

My current service configuration

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: orders
  clusterIP: 172.20.115.234
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
```

My Ingress Helm chart

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.name" $ }}-backend
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: forward
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "http://auth.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/api/v1/oauth2/auth"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: authorization
  labels:
    {{- include "api-gw.labels" $ | indent 4 }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: {{ .Values.deploy.host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /socket/events
            backend:
              serviceName: orders
              servicePort: 8000
```

My Service Helm chart

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "app.name" . }}
spec:
  {{ if not $isDebug -}}
  selector:
    app: {{ template "app.name" . }}
  {{ end -}}
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: {{ template "app.svc.port" . }}
    targetPort: {{ template "app.port" . }}
    nodePort: {{ .Values.service.exposedPort }}
    protocol: TCP



# Helpers..
# {{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
# {{- define "app.name" -}}
#     {{ default "default" .Chart.Name }}
# {{- end -}}

# {{- define "app.port" -}}
# 3000
# {{- end -}}

# {{- define "app.svc.port" -}}
# 8000
# {{- end -}}
```

Comment: Maybe this is somehow connected to round-robin load balancing. Try recreating the service with `clusterIP: None`, this way it'll expose IPs of service endpoints instead of single cluster IP.

Comment: Could you please provide the complete yamls for the services and deployments/pods including the `metadata`, `kind` and `api` fields?

Comment: Also the config for the ingress (to compare) would be nice.

Comment: @BeWu  I just updated those information

Comment: @akop I updated those information

Comment: What do you mean with "cannot connect"? `Connection refused` or HTTP-error?

Answer (score 2):

The services DNS name must be set in your container to access its VIP address.
Kubernetes automatically sets environmental variables in all pods which have the **same selector** as the **service**.

In your case, all pods with **selector A**, have environmental variables set in them when the container is deploying, that contain the services VIP and PORT.

The other pod with **selector B**, is not linked as an endpoints for the service, therefor, it does not contain the environmental variables needed to access the service.

Here is the  [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#accessing-the-service) related to your problem.

To solve this, you can setup a DNS service, which k8s offers as a cluster addon.
Just follow the documentation.